# Show that if C is a symmetric matrix C, then CC is positive semi-definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Show that if $C$ is a symmetric matrix, then $C^2$ is positive semi-definite.

I am trying for a while now to prove it but can not get right answer

Comment: Hint: You can diagonalize the matrix

Comment: This is interesting, I thought that for *any* nxn real-valued matrix A, AA was semi-definite, and symmetry is not a requirement. Perhaps my memory serves me wrongly?

Comment: Also, I seem to remember that all symmetric matrices are already positive semi-definite.

Comment: @DBPriGuy You have a bad memory. Think of a diagonal matrix with $-1$ on the diagonal.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Ah, it seems I do have a poor memory. Thanks for the counter-example!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$x^TCCx=x^TC^TCx=(Cx)^TCx=\|Cx\|^2$$

**Added:** Note that this is the standard definition of positive semi-definite. If you know the one with eigenvalues, let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $CC$ and let $u$ be a correspoding eigenvector.

Then 
$$\|Cu \|^2= u^T(CCu)=u^T \lambda u= \lambda \| u \|^2$$

Comment: Yeah but I can prove something like CC is positive semi-definite?

Comment: @FurqanMohiUDin That is the usual definition of positive semi-definite. If you are familiar with the one with eigenvalues, check the addon.

Comment: Can you elaborate further?

Answer (score 0):

If $C$ is symmetric, then $C = C^T$, whence $C^2 = CC = C^TC$.  Therefore for any vector $x$,

$\langle x, CCx\rangle = \langle x, C^TCx \rangle = \langle Cx, Cx \rangle \ge 0, \tag {1}$

and I think this does the trick!

Comment: Is it possible to get some expression for CC only?

Comment: @Furqan Mogi U Din:  not quite sure what you're asking here . . .